# How to see if ajax has been added to a simple node form?

Tags: forms, ajax

This very simple #ajax customisation to a node form is not working. How can I tell whether the callback has been added? I want to calculate a field if the first field is changed.

```
function cbi_currency_form_node_bond_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface 
   $form_state, $form_id) {

    $form['field_bond_amt_issued']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'cbi_currency_convert_usd',
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-field-bond-usd-amt-issued-wrapper',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
       'message' => t('Converting to USD...'),
     ],
  ];
 $form['field_bond_amt_issued']['#prefix'] = t('checking to see an ajax element.');
}
```

Take the value from *field_bond_amt_issued* and calculate a value for *field_bond_usd_amt_issued*.

The callback is simply

```
function cbi_currency_convert_usd(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['output']['#value'] = 33;
  return $form['output'];
}
```

I don't see any xhr requests when reviewing in the network console in the browser.

Comment: Using xdebug to step through the code would be the easiest way to see the callback called. But that prefix looks odd? What is "$form['output']" related to?

Comment: I've had hit and miss in the past with x-debug on the callback. I can't see it being hit in the network view, so am  assuming it isn't even being triggered. Xdebug definitely not picking it up.

Comment: So it's a widget form element not a standard form? Xdebug would show you the form element structure.

Comment: Standard content editing form. I can see the form structure.

Comment: Yes - is #ajax being added into the right part of the structure, though? See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277008/how-to-implement-ajax-callback-on-form-alter-for-entity-field

Comment: Ah - thank  you  $form['field_bond_amt_issued']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = [